# Openshift: Endpoints/Service for External MongoDB: Error No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, openshift, mongodb-replica-set

I am deploying my spring boot application in Openshift and the same uses external mongodb cluster for which I have created Endpoints/Service Objects. In my application.properties file I am using service name and when I try to call some API I am getting below error

No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your configurations as following link.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html

Comment: In my scenerio, i have to connect to external mongodb replicaset. I guess what is happening incorrect is oc service cannot resolve which of the node is acting as master. This documentation i have already read and my objects are already created. This error is thrown at runtime